# Python variable assigned by an outside module is accessible for printing but not for assignment in the target module

Tags: python, scoping

I have two files, one is in the webroot, and another is a bootstrap located one folder above the web root (this is CGI programming by the way).

The index file in the web root imports the bootstrap and assigns a variable to it, then calls a a function to initialize the application. Everything up to here works as expected.

Now, in the bootstrap file I can print the variable, but when I try to assign a value to the variable an error is thrown. If you take away the assignment statement no errors are thrown.

I'm really curious about how the scoping works in this situation. I can print the variable, but I can't asign to it. This is on Python 3.

**index.py**

```
# Import modules
import sys
import cgitb;

# Enable error reporting
cgitb.enable()
#cgitb.enable(display=0, logdir="/tmp")

# Add the application root to the include path
sys.path.append('path')

# Include the bootstrap
import bootstrap

bootstrap.VAR = 'testVar'

bootstrap.initialize()
```

**bootstrap.py**

```
def initialize():
    print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
    print(VAR)
    VAR = 'h'
    print(VAR)
```

Thanks.

Edit: The error message

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'VAR' referenced before assignment 
      args = ("local variable 'VAR' referenced before assignment",) 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of UnboundLocalError object at 0x00C6ACC0>
```

Comment: Might help to post your error message.

Comment: And your indents are showing on your bootstrap.py listing.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
def initialize():
    global VAR
    print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
    print(VAR)
    VAR = 'h'
    print(VAR)
```

Without 'global VAR' python want to use local variable VAR and give you "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'VAR' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Thanks, your post pointed me in the right direction.

Further info can be found here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare it global, pass it instead and return it if you need to have a new value, like this:

```
def initialize(a):
    print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
    print a
    return 'h'

----

import bootstrap
b = bootstrap.initialize('testVar')
```

Comment: Yes that will get around the scoping issue and I use that method in other situations; but in this situation the index.py file isn't supposed to do any kind of processing, it's only supposed to set a few values. The bootstrap is actually responsible for loading another class which does the processing